# How to assign variable in unique way for complement in subtraction

Tags: java, variables, variable-assignment

I am trying to assign variable "complement" such that expression `Math.abs(array[i]-complement)==diff` is true, but I am confused how to implement this. I considered trying to use conditionals, in the case that `array[i]` is greater than `diff`, then what would happen to `complement`, but these conditionals are not always true in all cases. Can someone suggest to me whether this is possible, or not, and if not, what should I do?

Essentially I am trying to find how many ways in an array there exists a pair where their difference is equal to a certain number (variable `diff`), and I want to find the "complement" so I can quickly look up in a hash table for O(N) time complexity.

Comment: Hi, what do you mean?

Comment: So I have a variable called "diff," and I am looping over an array of values. I also have a hashmap<int,int> with all these values and their indices loaded. I want to find how many pairs in the array where their absolute difference is equal to diff. So for each iteration, the two informations I know is: the current value array[i] and the difference. Then, I want to find the complement where array[i]-complement==difference, or complement-array[i]==difference. I need to assign this value in a way that meets both cases so then I can look it up in the hashmap to see if it exists.

Comment: If we were doing the same problem but looking for the specific sum, then at each iteration in the loop, the variable complement would be equal to: sum-array[i], since for addition it doesn't matter which number is larger, but I'm not sure how to do this for a specific difference.

Comment: Can't you use a HashMap where the keys are the complements (2 for each array element) and the values are the array elements? This is basically just the 2-diff problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is basically just the `2-diff` problem.

I can write out the psuedocode, but the implementation is up to you!

### Preface

Your code should run in `O(n)`, so that gives you an idea of how you would want to implement this solution. `O(n)` suggests that you are looping through your numbers one by one, and that there should not be any nested loops!

You also want to use a `HashMap` to be able to loop up values quickly.
We use a hashmap to store the complements of each number, so that we can encounter them later!

### Psuedocode

```
let nums be our array of numbers
let diff be our difference
let hash be a hashtable under SUHA

for each num in nums:
    if (num in hash):
        (num, hash[num]) is our pair!
    let c1 = num + diff
    let c2 = num - diff

    hash[c1] = num
    hash[c2] = num
```

Thats it!

### Intuition

The hashmap stores all the complements of the numbers, so when we are looking into the hashmap, we are basically asking, "is this number a complement of another number we have already seen?"

Comment: Hi Sorry for late reply but I was able to implement this idea.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: @bird74572 no problem. Glad I could help